# React Re-render on State Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const Feed = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function () {
 return {
  data: {}
 }
},

componentDidMount: function () {
axios.all([
  getAllTeams(), getAllDrivers()
]).then((results) => {
    let teams = results[0].data;
    let drivers = results[1].data;
    let newDrivers = normaliseDrivers(drivers);
    var data = normaliseData(teams, newDrivers);
    this.setState({
      data: data
    })
  })
},

sortAndRenderPanels () {
let teamsArr = Object.values(this.state.data);
teamsArr.sort(function(a,b) {
  return (a.positions[0][2016] > b.positions[0][2016])
    ? 1 : ((b.positions[0][2016] > a.positions[0][2016])
    ? -1 : 0);
});
return teamsArr.map ((data, i) => {
  return (
      <MyPanel
        key={i}
        data={data}
      />
  )
})
},

sortAlphabeticallyAndRender () {
let teamsArr = Object.values(this.state.data);
var sorted = teamsArr.sort(function(a, b){
  var textA = a.name.toUpperCase();
  var textB = b.name.toUpperCase();
  return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
});
return sorted.map((data, i) => {
  return (
    <MyPanel
      key={i}
      data={data}
    />
  )
 })
},

handleAlphabetClick (e) {
e.preventDefault();
this.sortAlphabeticallyAndRender(this.state);
this.forceUpdate(function () {
  return this.state.data;
});
},

render: function () {
const cards = this.sortAndRenderPanels();
return (
  <div id="feed">
    <Button id='sort-button' onClick={this.handleAlphabetClick} type="button" className="btn btn-warning" aria-label="Left Align">
      <span > Sort Alphabetically</span>
    </Button>
    {cards}
  </div>
)
}
});
```

On button Click I want to re-render the panels, to show in alphabetical order. I know my function to order them correctly works, and logs to the console with the data in the correct order, but I cannot seem to force an update to re-render the state.

Comment: As a react best practices, never ever do forceUpdate (until you are sure why you are doing force update). user setState() for  fire render method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing the force update, always make the change in `state` variable, it will automatically `re-render` the `ui`, Whenever you are `sorting` the `array`, update the `state` value with sorted `array`, And write a separate method to create the Panels, your Panels will updated automatically without `forceupdate`, Try this:

```
const Feed = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            data: {},
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function () {
        axios.all([
            getAllTeams(), getAllDrivers()
        ]).then((results) => {
            let teams = results[0].data;
            let drivers = results[1].data;
            let newDrivers = normaliseDrivers(drivers);
            var data = normaliseData(teams, newDrivers);
            var value = this.sortAndRenderPanels(data);
            this.setState({ data: value})
      })
    },

    sortAndRenderPanels: function (data) {
        let teamsArr = Object.values(data);
        teamsArr.sort(function(a,b) {
            return (a.positions[0][2016] > b.positions[0][2016])
            ? 1 : ((b.positions[0][2016] > a.positions[0][2016])
            ? -1 : 0);
        });
        return teamsArr || [];
    },

    sortAlphabeticallyAndRender: function (data) {
        let teamsArr = Object.values(data);
        teamsArr.sort(function(a, b){
            var textA = a.name.toUpperCase();
            var textB = b.name.toUpperCase();
            return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
        });
        return teamsArr;
    },

    handleAlphabetClick: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let data = this.sortAlphabeticallyAndRender(this.state.data);
        this.setState({data:data});
    },

    createPanel: function (){
        return this.state.data.map((data, i) => {
            return (
                <MyPanel
                    key={i}
                    data={data}
                />
            )
        })
    }

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div id="feed">
                <Button id='sort-button' onClick={this.handleAlphabetClick} type="button" className="btn btn-warning" aria-label="Left Align">
                    <span > Sort Alphabetically</span>
                </Button>
                {this.createPanel()}
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Mayank, this code does not seem to respond. Thanks for the answer tho.

Comment: whats the error u r getting, because i am sure about the code it should work :)

Comment: `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` I believe this is in the `sortAlphabeticallyAndRender()` as the data arrives as an `object`, and I am converting to an `array`

Comment: this was happening,  because i forgot to remove this line `const cards = this.sortAndRenderPanels();` inside of the render method, try the updated code, it will work :), because in that case data was null, and then it Object.values tries to get the values.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks @Mayank

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong, the forceUpdate() method will call the render() method.

In the render, you're calling :

```
const cards = this.sortAndRenderPanels();
```

And print them with { cards }

I think you need to move cards in this.state

In your componentDidMount() callback add this :

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    let obj = this;
    axios.all([
        getAllTeams(), getAllDrivers()
    ]).then((results) => {
        let teams = results[0].data;
        let drivers = results[1].data;
        let newDrivers = normaliseDrivers(drivers);
        var data = normaliseData(teams, newDrivers);
        this.setState({
            data: data,
            cards: obj.sortAndRenderPanels()
        })
    })
}
```

And in your click handler add this :

```
handleAlphabetClick (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        cards: this.sortAlphabeticallyAndRender(this.state)
    });
}
```

The re-render should normally occur. If not add this :

```
componentDidUpdate: function() {
    this.forceUpdate();
}
```

Last you need to change in your render {cards} with { this.state.cards }

Regards

Comment: its a very bad practice to store the Ui items in the state variable, always store the data and do the change only in data, then create the ui with updated data.

Comment: I have tried using this code, with and without `componentDidUpdate()` but it does not seem to work, thanks for the help tho.